# DB::table($table)->with($relation); it's possible?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

If I use models this is easily resolved, but if I don't have the availability of using models, would it be possible to get the result equivalent to `->with()` with `DB::table`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Here is why

Laravel models are using Eloquent, which is an ORM library.

For example, a class model could have many teachers relations, and if you want to fetch a class with all the teachers, you could do something like:

```
$class = Classes::with('teachers')->find($id);

// $class->teachers contain all the teachers in the given class
```

With the query builder, you would need to do something like

```
$class = DB::table('classes')->find($id);

$teachers = DB::table('teachers')->where('class_id', $class->id)->get();
```

You can look into the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent

[Ref Thread](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/dbtable-vs-model)

Answer (score -1):

No this is not possible Now,
Because DB row not supported elequent relation
you should use by ORM formate.
Here is some example :-
$user = user::with('school')->get();

Comment: This answer is already available in other answers.